# Compiling issue in C very basic program

Tags: c, cs50

Here are the errors:

```
mario.c:23:25: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘int’
for (int levelCounter, int usrHeight, int paddIt = usrHeight - 1, char hashMaker, int hashCounter;(levelCounter <= usrHeight);)

                      ^


mario.c:25:39: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘paddIt’
printf("%'' * paddIt %c*hashCounter"paddIt,hashMaker,hashCounter);
                                    ^
```

^ identifies where the compiler is saying the error is occuring.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int usrHeight = 0;
int levelCounter = 0;
int paddIt = 0;
int hashCounter = 2;
char hashMaker = "#";

do 
{
    printf("How high?\n");
    int usrHeight = GetInt();
}
while ( usrHeight > 23 || usrHeight < 0);
if ( usrHeight >= 0 && usrHeight <= 23);
{
    printf("constructing...\n");

}
for (int levelCounter, int usrHeight, int paddIt = usrHeight - 1, char hashMaker, int hashCounter;(levelCounter <= usrHeight);)
                 *^ This is where the first error is occuring*
{
    printf("%'' * paddIt %c*hashCounter"paddIt,hashMaker,hashCounter);
                                                *^ And here is where the second is* 
    paddIt = paddIt - 1;
    levelCounter = levelCounter + 1;
    hashCounter = hashCounter + 1;
}
}
```

What is it exactly I am doing that is  wrong?

Comment: Wow, quite a mess.  Not even sure where to begin.  Why don't you remove code and slowly add it back in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have just one declaration in the initial position of the `for` loop in C99 and later:

```
for (int levelCounter, usrHeight, paddIt = usrHeight - 1, hashMaker, hashCounter;
     ...condition...; ...increment...
    )
```

However, you have a problem; `usrHeight` is uninitialized, so `paddIt` is an indeterminate value.  And I had to change the type of `hashMaker` to `int`.  You can only use one type.

Frankly, declaring that many variables in the loop control is wrong.  If you do it, all of them should be initialized.  Otherwise, you could use:

```
for (int levelCounter; ...condition...; ...increment...)
{
    int usrHeight = -1, paddIt = usrHeight - 1, hashCounter = 0;
    char hashMaker;
    ...loop body...
}
```

This fixes some problems. If you need the values of the variables preserved across iterations of the loop (this defines and initializes them on each iteration), then the extra variables should be defined outside the loop.  You would seldom declare more than one, and even more rarely more than two, variables in a `for` loop.  I could almost justify:

```
for (int i = min, j = max; i < j; i++, j--)
```

which has one variable counting up while the other counts down, though you could compute `j` in the body of the loop, especially if `min` is 0.

Someone who presented me with (a fixed version of) the original code for code review would get very short shrift from me — go rewrite the code more clearly.

---

The second problem is a missing comma where the compiler said it expected a `)`:

```
printf("%'' * paddIt %c*hashCounter"paddIt,hashMaker,hashCounter);
```

should be:

```
printf("%'' * paddIt %c*hashCounter", paddIt, hashMaker, hashCounter);
```

The first part of that is actually a malformed conversion specification; you might mean `"%%''..."` or you might mean something else altogether, such as:

```
printf("%' *.*c", paddIt, hashMaker, hashCounter);
```

The single quote is still not relevant to the `%c` conversion specifier (so the behaviour is undefined), but it is part of POSIX 2008 of [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) — it adds thousands separators when necessary for large numbers.

---

I didn't notice that you already declared all the variables you mention in your `for` loop.  It looks as though you could reduce that loop to:

```
for (levelCounter = 0; levelCounter <= usrHeight; levelCounter++)
{
    printf("%.*s", paddIt, "");
    for (int i = 0; i < hashCounter; i++)
        putchar('#'); 
    paddIt = paddIt - 1;
    hashCounter = hashCounter + 1;
}
```

This uses the information from a comment about the intended format which was not clear from the original question.

Comment: I was using the %c to print the hashmarks and the single quotes were to denote a space done n times where n=paddIt, How would I got about making printf print an n amount of spaces followed by and x amount of # marks?

Comment: The space you can do, as it happens, with a sort of cheat: `printf("'%.*s'", paddIt, "");`.  This prints a string of minimum width specified by `paddIt`, using blanks as the filler for the (right-justified) empty string.  However, `printf()` does not support printing a single non-blank character a specified number of times.  You can specify minimum and maximum widths, but not repeat counts (and the 'cheat' is using a width as a repeat count). I'd use `for (int i = 0; i < hashCounter; i++) putchar('#');`, possibly wrapped as a tiny function if it was an idiom that would occur more than once.

Comment: in your last edit you have a for statement inside of another for statement with the second for need {}?

Comment: @user3273247: when there's a single statement in the body of a loop, there is no need to use braces around it. They're permissible; they're not mandatory.  There are those who say 'add braces everywhere'; I'm not of that school.  However, if the body of the loop were an `if` statement (with or without its own `else`), or a `switch`, then I'd use the braces (even though they're still officially optional).

Comment: @Jonathanin the `printf("%.*s", paddIt, "");` statement what exactly is `("%.*s", paddIt, "")` doing? From what I can tell `%s` is the `paddIt` string? but I'm not sure what the `.*`is doing to it. and when `""` is declared what is calling that in the statement or better phrased what is using this?

Comment: In part (detail), see the `printf()` URL in the answer.  In a `printf()` conversion specification, the `*` means 'read an `int` from the argument list'. The variable `paddIt` is an integer.  The `"%.*s"` notation can be thought of as similar to `%.10s`, except that the 10 is dynamic and comes from the `paddIt` argument.  The `%.10s` notation means that the string printed should be no more than 10 characters long.  If the string is shorter than 10 characters, it will be printed right justified; if longer, it will be truncated. The `""` empty string is the value to be printed by the `s`.

Answer (score -2):

Why can't you convert this for loop to a while loop? this will do the same

```
while(levelCounter <= usrHeight)

{
 printf("%'' * paddIt %c*hashCounter",paddIt,hashMaker,hashCounter);

 paddIt = paddIt - 1;
 levelCounter = levelCounter + 1;
 hashCounter = hashCounter + 1;
}
```